# Angular 6 : Nested forms with conditional custom validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Im working on some nested forms validations based on some conditions but not able to do it, this made me to realize where I'm in Angular.

This needs to do 2 things ~
1. Check **Employee** of **Employees** formArray exists in **PermanantEmployee** formGroup of **PermanantEmployees** formArray

2. If exists then only **required** validation should work for **eName** and **eContact** formControls of  **Employee** formgroup of **Employees** formArray

Following is my object hierarchy ~

```
Company //formgroup
    name //formControl
    address //formControl
    Employees //formArray
        Employee //formgroup
            eId //formControl
            eName //formControl
            eContact //formControl
        Employee
            eId
            eName
            eContact
    PermanantEmployees //formArray
        PermanantEmployee //formgroup
            Employee //formControl
            eAddress //formControl
            eSalary //formControl
            eJoinDate //formControl
        PermanantEmployee
            Employee
            eAddress
            eSalary
            eJoinDate
```

I have gone through dozens of articles about nested forms, custom validation and even look deeply at formControl, formGroup, formArray but still Im in same situation.

Millions thanks to your time and help.

Vijay

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form ? I think it'd be a great fit for you. Also for the validation, I think the only way of doing that would be to have a global validation at the company level

Comment: Thanks @maxime1992, surely ll check ngx-sub-form, meanwhile how it can be done with validation at the company level?